# How to make WPF Menu control the Content of a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to build a dynamic menu in C# WPF.

I generate the Menu from a model with a ObservableCollection of other Models (Navigation), each model in this list has a Name and a Command. The models are listed in `<Window.Resources>` What I want is that when a `MenuItem` is clicked the `ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedPage}"` should change the content to the corresponding `UserControl`.

The code that I have so far is this. However I do not understand how to link the clicking of the MenuItem with the actual changing of the content.

```
<Window
  ....
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cm:HostListModel}">
        <uc:HostList />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cm:WorkerListModel}">
        <uc:WorkerList />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cm:MeasureListModel}">
        <uc:MeasureList />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cmg:ChartModel}">
        <uc:Chart />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>  
    ....
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"> 
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem x:Name="StartBtn" Header="_Start" Click="StartBtn_Click" />
            <MenuItem x:Name="SaveBtn" Header="_Save" Click="SaveBtn_Click" />
        </Menu>
        <Menu x:Name="Menu" IsMainMenu="true" ItemsSource="{Binding Navigation}">
            <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
                </Style>
            </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        </Menu>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Grid.Column="1">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedPage}"/>
    </Grid>      
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have tried a similar solution which worked but I did not like the look and feel of that menu. Here I could just click on a "button" and the content changed to the clicked item. It looked like this.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Navigation}" BorderThickness="0">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
........
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Grid.Column="1">
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxMenu Path=SelectedItem}"/>
</Grid>
```